# Loading a drupal core(node.add) form via a route and a controller

Tags: controller, routes, drupal-8

I have a content type 'blog' which i can access the form via `'/node/add/blog'`..
I want to attach blogs to articles and I have gone ahead and created a local task menu for that.The problem is I can't get my $form to load via the link below in path.
`'module_name.routing.yml'`

`customblog.add_form:
  path: '/node/add/blog/{node}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_blog\Controller\CblogController::addBlog'
    _title: 'Attach blog to Article in the URL{node}'
  requirements:
    _node_add_access: 'node:blog'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: true
    parameters:
      node_type:
        with_config_overrides: true`

In my controller I have

```
public function addBlog(NodeTypeInterface $node_type, $node) {
$node_type = NodeTypeInterface::load('blog');

$entity = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage($node)->create(array(
  'type' => $node_type->id(),
));

//build form
$form = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($entity);

return $form;
}
```

I get an error

```
RuntimeException: Controller 
"Drupal\custom_blog\Controller\CblogController::addBlog()" requires that you 
provide a value for the "$node_type" argument (because there is no default 
value or because there is a non optional argument after this one)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by keeping the name of the arguments same as used in the routing file.

In your case: 
Change `/node/add/blog/{node}` to `/node/add/blog/{node_type}/{node}`